# adding classes to children

Tags: jquery

When I do 
`$('ul.latestnews ul li').parent().prev().text());` I get back the content of the targeted li. (word1 or word2 in this example).

But when I do

```
$('ul.latestnews ul li').addClass($(this).parent().prev().text());
```

It doesn't add the class. When I do a console.log on that last statement it just returns all the li's I am trying to add the class to.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
<ul class="latestnews">
    <li>word1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>my class should become word1</li>
        <li>my class should become word1</li>
    </ul>
    <li>word2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>my class must become word2</li>
    </ul>        
</ul>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: isn't that html invalid?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this in this case was not the element I intended to use with it but the window?

Comment: @Jarco. `this` is the DOM element only inside of jQuery **function**, like with `each`.

Comment: If i get this correctly $(this) refers always to the dom element of the function it is in? So when you do the .each(function(){$(this) it changes from the window to the funtion element?

Comment: @Jarco. I would chose different words for this... but I think you got it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still getting some expierence and all of you people helping me have a big "THANK YOU" from me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the DOM element only inside of a jQuery function, like `each`:

```
$('ul.latestnews ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).parent().prev().text());
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9xUB/4)
`this` in your code is probably the `Window` object...

Note that those kind of DOM traversal with `prev`, `parent` can break very easily if you change the DOM structure a bit, you might want to use other selector based of the elements classes.

Comment: Quick question bruv `.addClass(text)` what will this achieve, whys that? ++1 anyways on enlightenment `:)` hows life!

Comment: @Tats_innit. I didn't get your question, but life is good... :)

Comment: Saweet Bruv, Rocking \m/; I meant what will this do :`.addClass($(this).parent().prev().text());` its just add the `word1 word2` as class or something more, `:P`

Comment: Ah, too late night at my end then, my mind going tube light, got it `:)` thanks!! see you morrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the html code is not quite right as it should be like :

```
<ul class="latestnews">
    <li>word1</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>my class should become word1</li>
            <li>my class should become word1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>word2</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>my class must become word2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

then:

```
$("ul.latestnews ul > li").each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var className = $this.parents("li").first().prev().text();
    $this.addClass(className);
});
```

Comment: You are correct. This is sadly the default output from the joomla component k2. I will make a new k2 template that fixes this error.

Comment: Replace `.parents("li").first()` with => `.closest('li')`